# Increasing the margin between two clusters in a facet chart?

Tags: graph, charts, zoomcharts

In Zoomcharts, how can we increase the spacing between two clusters in a facet chart to make it look two separate entities?

Answer (score 0):

Use padding:

https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/full-reference/FacetChartSettingsSeriesColumnsStyle.html

this let's you set configure the padding of the series.